# Float comparison mismatch

Tags: java, android

I have an extremely weird error that I cannot figure out.

```
float distance = Utils.distance(this.spriteStartX, this.spriteStartY, this.getX(), this.getY());

Utils.log("D_Check: "+distance+" >= "+this.spriteDistance);

if(distance >= this.spriteDistance);
{
    Utils.log(distance+" is greater than "+this.spriteDistance);
}
```

In this code I determine the distance between where my sprite originated and its' current location. (for the sake of simplicity, this is 8.034246f). this.spriteDistance is 7000.0f.

In the debugger I am receiving:

```
D_Check: 8.034246 >= 7000.0
8.034246 is greater than 7000.0
```

Obviously something is very wrong with this. Have I missed something incredibly simple?

Comment: What's the datatype of spriteDistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the if statement.

```
if (distance >= this.spriteDistance)
{
    Utils.log(distance+" is greater than "+this.spriteDistance);
}
```

Comment: I was staring at it the whole damned time! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the if statement.